# python request post doesn't submit

Tags: python

I have a problem with request.post, instead of returning the html code with the results I get back the html code of the starting side.

```
import requests
def test(pdb):
   URL = "http://capture.caltech.edu/"
   r = requests.post(URL,files={"upfile": open( pdb)})
   content=r.text
   print(content)
   print(r.headers)



def main():
  test("Model.pdb")
```

Could it be that I have to define which postmethod I want to use? Because there are two in the html file. If this is the case how do I do that?(I want to use the second one.)

```
<FORM ACTION="result.cgi" METHOD=POST>
<form action="capture_ul.cgi" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I am aware that there are similar questions here but the answers there didn't help because the mistake was that params was used instead of files, which shouldn't be a problem here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're posting to the homepage, those forms suggest you should be posting to either `http://capture.caltech.edu/result.cgi` or `http://capture.caltech.edu/capture_ul.cgi`

Answer (score 2):

1 - You are posting to the wrong url, it should be `http://capture.caltech.edu/capture_ul.cgi`.

2 - There's an hidden field (`name='note'`) that must be sent (value of an empty string will be enough).

```
...
def test(pdb):
   URL = "http://capture.caltech.edu/capture_ul.cgi"
   r = requests.post(URL,files={"upfile": open(pdb)}, data={'note': ''})
   content=r.text
   print(content)
   print(r.headers)
...
```